# Logistic regression: why bothering with the sigmoid?

Tags: logistic

In Logistic Regression, testing:

```
sigmoid(a0 + a1*x1 + a2*x2 + ...)  >=  PERCENT_THRESHOLD
```

seems to me mathematically equivalent to testing:

```
(a0 + a1*x1 + a2*x2 + ...)  >=  LINEAR_THRESHOLD
```

such that:

```
sigmoid( LINEAR_THRESHOLD ) = PERCENT_THRESHOLD
```

Calculating the Sigmoid slows down optimisation. Why do we need to compute it, when we can get the same result without it?

Are there cases where calculating the Sigmoid is useful, or is it just a mathematical abstraction, that we can disregard in practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sigmoid is used to compress the data between 0 and 1 so you can use a percentage threshold. It also causes saturation of extreme values. If you want to use just a linear threshold it is possible but this won't be a logistic regression but a threshold model.

Comment: +1 One short comment: logistic regression returns probabilities. This is just about the interoperability of the results, but this makes choosing the threshold easier since without the sigmoid function the threshold can be anything on the real line and with probabilities you can easier come up with a reasonable cut-off threshold.